# NSNotification center may not respond to -object?

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying to make simple use of the NSNotification center inside my iPhone application, but I seem to be doing something wrong in this case.  I was under the impression that it was possible to retrieve an object associated with a particular message, or at least a reference to the object, but using the following example code I'm getting a warning,

"NSNotification center may not respond to -object"

```
- (void)addNewBookmark:(NSNotificationCenter *)notification {
    Bookmark *newBookMark = (Bookmark *)[notification object];
        //Do some stuff with the bookmark object
}
```

Indeed, when I compile and run the code, basically nothing I try to do with the contents of the object actually gets carried out - it's simply ignored.

The post code is as follows,

```
- (IBAction)save:(id) sender{
    //Sending the message with the related object
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"addNewBookmark"
     object:bookmark];
}
```

and the bookmark object itself is just a dictionary.  I also tried using the "userInfo" argument and passing the bookmark object through that, but the result was the same.

How should I be doing this?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addNewBookmark:` method should accept an NSNotification, not an NSNotificationCenter.

NSNotification should respond to `-object` as expected.

A notification center is the object in charge of keeping track of who is listening and sending notifications (not centers) to them.

Comment: oh dear I feel silly.  too quick with the autocomplete.  ill accept this as soon as the timer allows it.